# Q_REVISION meaning in Qt Class

Tags: c++, qt

what is `Q_REVISION` in Qt function body?
I saw this so many times in qt source codes.
I have looked into Qt documentation and i saw [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_REVISION) documentations says :

> Apply this macro to declarations of member functions to tag them with
>   a revision number in the meta-object system.

what does it means? and where can i use this `Q_REVISION`

Comment: docs: *This is useful when using the meta-object system to dynamically expose objects to another API, as you can match the version expected by multiple versions of the other API.*. I recommend reading the complete docs since it gives an example of its use.

Comment: that even makes it more complicated, can you simply explain whats going on and what is difference between `Q_REVISION(1)` and `Q_REVISION(3)`

Comment: @MoreMag, the difference is the version number of your property. For example if you are creating Lib with API and use this lib in another project you can check wich version of your API is installed on system. For example newer version could have some extra functionality or behavior is changed.For example like in QDataStream Calss of Qt: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of now this is only used by QtQml, when you need to use a C++ object in QML you must register it using this syntax.

```
qmlRegisterType<Foo>("MyModule", 1, 0, "Foo");
```

By doing so you can then import your module in QML and use the `Foo` object.
This syntax exposes to QML all methods and properties marked as `Q_REVISION(0)`, that as the documentation says, is the default value.

Let's say we have our class `Foo` that has several revisions.

```
class Foo : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(int normalProperty READ normalProperty)
    Q_PROPERTY(int newProperty READ newProperty REVISION 1)
    Q_PROPERTY(int newerProperty READ newerProperty REVISION 2)

public:
    Foo();
public slots:
    int normalProperty() { return 0; }
    Q_REVISION(1) int newProperty() { return 1; }
    Q_REVISION(2) int newerProperty() { return 2; }
};
```

By using the previous syntax we'll be able to only use the `normalProperty` in QML, to use other revision we must do this.

```
qmlRegisterType<Foo, 1>("MyModule", 1, 1, "Foo");
```

Notice the difference in the template arguments, the previous one doesn't have the have revision number after the class name. It's also good practice to increment the minor version of the module, that is the third argument of the function.
This way you'll be able to use `normalProperty` and `newProperty` in QML.

```
qmlRegisterType<Foo, 2>("MyModule", 1, 2, "Foo");
```

With this call instead you'll be able to use all three properties, `normalProperty`, `newProperty` and `newerProperty`.

You can find even more information on the [QObject documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html#type-revisions-and-versions).

Great question by the way, I didn't know this macro. I hope we both learned something new. :)

Comment: that was a perfect answer ty